# How to customise "My View" in Mantis bug tracker?

Tags: bug-tracking, issue-tracking, mantis

The "My View" in Mantis shows the following sections:

1. Unassigned
2. Resolved
3. Monitored by Me
4. Reported by Me
5. Recently Modified

Which PHP file in Mantis generates this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to your question is: my_view_page.php

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still the same answer. If someone wants to know, you can add this array in your config_inc.php file :

```
  $g_my_view_boxes = array(
            'assigned'      => '1',
            'unassigned'    => '2',
            'reported'      => '3',
            'resolved'      => '10',
            'recent_mod'    => '7',
            'monitored'     => '6',
            'feedback'      => '0',
            'verify'        => '0',
            'my_comments'   => '0',
    );
```

You should change integer to give the order you want.